# Create a file which can be renamed while in use

Tags: c++

I have a application which has two sub modules. Also their is custom Log class written to log module activities.Requirement I am working on is each module should create log file with same name and write log into that. To explain it better consider initial run in which module1 is wrting logs in app.log now when another session of application starts with module2 it should also create app.log and start writing. but before that old app.log should get rename to something app.log.1.

Issue I am facing when log file is open with one module function fails to rename. I am working in C++ on window 7. To create a file I am using - 
std::ofstream s_ofs.open("app.log", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by synchronizing access to the Log class object. An approach could be as follows:

1. Application creates the Log class object on startup Create a
   Synchronization object (say Mutex) which protects access to the
   Logging
2. Have the Log method accept a flag which will differentiate
   between accesses from two different modules
3. Module1 gains access and  starts logging
4. When module2 wants to write, the Logger will detect that it has a Log request from another module, and will close the file and then rename it and create another log file with the same     name

Comment: Workable I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not allow this. When you open a file, for writing *or* for reading, it's locked and you can't do operations such as rename or delete while the file is open.

You might want to reconsider your design. Either so that each submodule have its own *uniquely* named log file. Or use a logging module that can receive logging input from multiple sources and multiplex those into a single file.

Comment: I was planning to replicate something as used in log4net in C#. It allows you to rename current log file while in use. Anyother model to open file which may allow code to rename this file.

Comment: Interesting side note: Opening files as [mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows does not have this restriction. This is for example the reason why can move and rename dlls while they are being loaded. You cannot however delete mapped files or move them to a different disk.